# iAd load ads sucessfully, but bannerLoaded property is NO

Tags: ios, iad

I use ADBannerView to load ads, and use bannerLoaded property to detect result. the bannerLoaded is always NO, but the ADBannerView actually load ads successfully (I reverse bannerLoaded in if statement to prove this) . And bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: doesn't log any error.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self load_iAd];
}

- (void)load_iAd
{
    //init iAd
    // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
    if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    } else {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    }
    _bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

    if (_bannerView==nil) {
        NSLog(@"ad view is nil");
    }

    //place iAd
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

    // all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
    CGSize sizeForBanner = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    // compute the ad banner frame
    CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;
    NSLog(@"_bannerView.bannerLoaded %f",_bannerView.bannerLoaded);
    if (_bannerView.bannerLoaded) {

        // bring the ad into view
        contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height;   // shrink down content frame to fit the banner below it
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height;
        bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width;

        // if the ad is available and loaded, shrink down the content frame to fit the banner below it,
        // we do this by modifying the vertical bottom constraint constant to equal the banner's height
        //
        NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
        verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height;
        NSLog(@"verticalBottomConstraint.constant:%f",verticalBottomConstraint.constant);
        [self.view layoutSubviews];

    } else {
        // hide the banner off screen further off the bottom
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"no iAd");
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
    }

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think, at the time if initialisation _bannerView, it is not loaded that is the reason `bannerLoaded` property is `NO`.

Better u can perform hide and show of banner view on the delegate methods of `ADBannerView` for example in your case

```
- (void)load_iAd
 {
    //init iAd
    // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
    if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
       _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
    } else {
       _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    }
    _bannerView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];

    if (_bannerView==nil) {
       NSLog(@"ad view is nil");
    }
}

//in the delegate method of ADBannerView 
//int this delegate method better not show banner
- (void)bannerViewWillLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
 {
   _bannerView.hidden = YES;
    NSLog(@"banner view will loaded");
 }

 //this is the rite time to show banner view and animations to show banner view 
 - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    _bannerView.hidden = NO;
   //place iAd
   CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds;

   // all we need to do is ask the banner for a size that fits into the layout area we are using
   CGSize sizeForBanner = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

   // compute the ad banner frame
   CGRect bannerFrame = _bannerView.frame;

     // bring the ad into view
    contentFrame.size.height -= sizeForBanner.height;   // shrink down content frame to fit the banner below it
    bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    bannerFrame.size.height = sizeForBanner.height;
    bannerFrame.size.width = sizeForBanner.width;

    // if the ad is available and loaded, shrink down the content frame to fit the banner below it,
    // we do this by modifying the vertical bottom constraint constant to equal the banner's height
    //
    NSLayoutConstraint *verticalBottomConstraint = self.bottomConstraint;
    verticalBottomConstraint.constant = sizeForBanner.height;
    NSLog(@"verticalBottomConstraint.constant:%f",verticalBottomConstraint.constant);
    [self.view layoutSubviews];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
    }];
}

//int this delegate method better hide the banner view
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
 _bannerView.hidden = YES;
 NSLog(@"banner view did't load");
 //hear goes hide animations for banner view 
 //....code to hide banner

 }
```

and i also suggest that use a shared object of banner view, it will be use full if u are using banner in some other view controller's in your app ....

hope this helps u .. :)